# s3fs: software caused connection abort while accessing s3 mounted folder

Tags: linux, amazon-s3, fuse, s3fs

I have mounted three s3 buckets namely **1) abc.example.com 2) bdf.example.com 3) xyz.example.com** using FUSE based s3fs. I am able to access (read and write) abc.example.com and bdf.example.com from mounted location (/mnt/s3/). But when I try to access xyz.example.com. I am getting the following error.
**ERROR: s3fs software caused connection abort**

Comment: Please include `s3fs -d -d -f -o f2 -o curldbg` debug output.

Answer (score 0):

I also had this issue while trying to copy a file to the mounted directory(i.e. the s3).

I solved it by ensuring the values of `AWSACCESSKEYID` and `AWSSECRETACCESSKEY` were the correct. In the host where `s3fs` is executed.

Answer (score -1):

**Soln: Add the bucket which you want to mount to S3 user policy (Ex: mount-user-policy).**